# Linux native aio still needs to be blocked

Tags: linux, io

I'm studying linux native AIO lib (libaio.h) but really confused about why it's called 'asynchronous I/O'. Since after io_submit(), you always need to io_getevents() to poll until the I/O return. The process still may be blocked, right? So what's the difference/advantage compared to select/pselect/poll?

Answer (score 0):

Using AIO is advantageous because the I/O is performed directly from the user buffers, avoiding a copy to a kernel buffer.  If reading, the kernel "owns" the buffer and the application must not touch the buffer until the I/O is complete.  Same for writing, the kernel owns the buffer until the I/O completes and only then is the buffer available for reuse.

The idea is to start multiple transfers and while the I/O transfers are in flight you can go do something else.  Eventually you get a SIGIO delivered to the application and then you can check which I/O completed.